# Stored procedure take 80 seconds to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-profiler

I have a Stored Procedure that seems to be taking way too long in comparison to other stored procedures. I have ran a SQL profiler and it is taking upto 80 seconds for this to return data on some occasions via an ASP.NET application, is there something wrong with the stored procedure?

```
USE [Payments]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[liftsGetByCustomerNumber]    Script Date: 30/01/2017 15:35:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[liftsGetByCustomerNumber] 

    @mprn BIGINT,
    @startDate DATE,
    @endDate DATE,
    @customerNumber nVarChar(50)


AS
BEGIN

SELECT b.[transactionId]
      ,b.[accountGUID]
      ,b.[transactionDate]
      ,b.[transactionAmount]
      ,b.[transactionType]
      ,b.[transactionDeposit]
FROM accounts  as a,transactions as b
where a.GUID = b.accountGUID
and  a.mprn = @mprn
and a.customernumber = @customerNumber
and b.transactionDate between @startdate and @enddate
and b.transactionAmount > 0
and b.transactionType not in ('00','0', '0N', '99')
order by transactionDate, transactionType
END
```

There are only 80,000 accounts and 200,000 transactions in the table so i cannot foresee this being so slow, what other problems could I check for?

Comment: First suggestion is to add `option (recompile)`.  Second is to learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: make an index on accounts.customernumber and transactions.transactionDate

Comment: Please provide query plan and give details of table / index structures

Comment: It won't make it faster but it is better form not use the old ANSI sytax and replace your WHERE a.GUID = b.accountGUID with FROM accounts  as a inner join transactions as b on a.GUID = b.accountGUID that the

Comment: what is option recompile?

Comment: I have added an index and put inner join to replace guid=guid line but still suffering poor performance, this was previously working without noticeable time lags, could this be a latency issue of some sort?

Comment: What indexes are available on accounts and transactions? Also, if you run the query directly in Sql Server Management Studio (meaning copy the body of the proc and run it as *ad hoc* Sql), does it run much quicker?

Comment: @Jay  Here is a write up on `option (recompile)` that you may find useful: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/12/recompile-hints-and-execution-plan-caching/

Comment: please paste execution plan along with table schema,counts

Comment: Option Recompile creates a new execution plan every time the proc is executed. If you stored proc does not change, i.e. the columns used in the query, option recompile will have no effect.

Comment: Issue is now resolved look like a combination of adding indexes and properly joining solved this issue thanks for your help guys if you want to post an answer I will accept it